# How do I create a multiple page app with a login component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Recently I've tried building a web platform trough React. Everything's fine, everything's work ecc.
But I've run in many problems when I tried to create a different page for the user login:

1. I already had Routes in my code, so when I tried to add other Routes to another js file they simply didn't work.
2. I have no clue how to do the authentication in react router, I've tried in many ways, followed many tutorials but nothing worked out.

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Feed}/>
    <Route path="/user" component={Profilo}/>
    <Route path='/explore-page' component={ExplorePage} />
    <Route path='/events-page' component={EventsPage} />
    <Route path='/calendar-page' component={CalendarPage} />
    <Route path='/stats-page' component={StatsPage} />
    <Route path='/form' component={FormPage}/>
    <Route path="/user" component={Profilo}/>
    <Route path="/user/:userId" component={Profilo} />
</Switch>
```

This is all the routes I'm currently using inside a div to get the react component rendered.
As I said before adding other routes in an upper file wouldn't give me a response.

So, in the end, I'm gonna ask you where should I put the route for the login and the home? In there or I should just moving everything?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: if you want to prevent user from visit some pages (without logged in), you need to implement ProtectedRoute (just google it).

Comment: You can maintain one stack for login seperately i.e. route is different. And after login just render other stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way is adding the logic to handle authentication in your render function.

If the user is not authenticated. Redirect to the login page. Otherwise, go to your component

```
render() {
    if (!this.props.isAuth) {
        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
                <Redirect to="/" />
            </Switch>
        );
    }
    return (<Switch>
        <Route
            // your router
        />
    </Switch>);
}
```